# Which form of 終わる should I use here?

Tags: word-choice

> A :  会議は何時ごろ終わりますか？
>   B : もうしばらく____はずですが。
>
> 1.終わり　　2.終わる　　3.終わった　　4.終わらない

I've been pondering why the answer has to be 4.
Can anyone explain it to me please?

Answer (score 9):

The correct answer should be #4 終わらない because しばらく means "for a while" and not "*in* a while / *after* a while" or "a while *ago*".

> もうしばらく終わらないはずですが。
>   *lit.* I think it won't finish for a little while more."
>   → "I think it will continue for a little while more."

To use #1, #2 and #3, you'd need to change the sentence this way:

> 1 → もうしばらく**で**終わり**の**はずですが。(adding の since 終わり is a noun form)
>   "I think it will finish in a little while more. / soon."
>   2 → もう しばらく**で**終わる / しばらく**すれば**終わる はずですが。
>   "I think it will finish in a little while more. / soon."
>   3 → もうしばらく**前に**終わったはずですが。
>   "I think it already finished a while ago." (The もう here means "already".)

Comment: Today, I see "もうすく終わると思います"  Why this is usable without using で？

Comment: @Kiw You can say もうすぐ終わると思います cos 「(もう)すぐ」 is an adverb. (It's もうす**ぐ** , not もうすく.)

Comment: Is もう an adverb, しばらか a noun so I have to use で ? I search しばらく in a dict. It shows that しばらく is an adverb too. I understand as you mentioned that もうしばらく is for a while. Thus I know that if I use もうしばらく終わる, it means “It’ll be over for a while”(After a while it will be starting again)  Does もう+すぐ have any meaning of “for” as もう+しばらく have ?

Comment: @Kiw (with or without もう,) しばらく can be an adverb meaning "**for** a while", eg 「しばらくお待ちください」"Please wait **for** a while." しばらく can also be a noun meaning "a while", but cannot be an adverb meaning "**in** a while". To say "in/after a while" or "soon", you say 「(もう)しばらく**で**終わる」or 「もうすぐ終わる」. (「すぐ」「もうすぐ 」 are adverbs meaning "very soon" "soon". 「すぐ終わる」「すぐに終わる」 would mean "will end very soon / quickly"). 「もうしばらく終わる」 doesn't really make sense. To say "It'll be over for a while (After a while it will be starting again)", I'd say しばらく休む.

Comment: Thanks. 「もうしばらくでおわる」Is で after しばらく because しばらく is a Noun ? Use で to show how it ends ?

Comment: @Kiw 「[duration]+で」 means "in/after~~". eg インスタントラーメンは**3分で**できる。Instant ramen cooks **in 3 minutes**. **５分で**行きます。I will go **in five minutes**. (See [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/23010/9831)), この本を**３時間で**読み終わった。 I finished reading this book **in three hours**. (See [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/725/9831))