# Why is it 4分で売り切りだった and not 4分に売り切りだった？

Tags: particles

Why is it 4分で売り切りだった and not 4分に売り切りだった？

Could someone help explain why で is used and not に?

Comment: `売り切りだった` -- Are you sure it's not 売り切**れ**だった ?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/23010/9831

Answer (score 1):

で means a range of time while に does not.